# "Solved" Query Excel date fields using ODBC return null

Tags: excel, jdbc, odbc

I use the following configuration to run a java program to extract data from a excel file. Some of these columns have data with time-stamp context.

- Platform: Win 7 (x64)
- ODBC: Excel (x32) [via Office 2010]; rows to scan = 8
- Excel schema: "some fields", "date field 1", "date field 2", "date field 3", "other fields"
- Date format shown in excel: dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM
- Java 1.6
- JDBC/ODBC driver: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver

I tried the following (simplified) queries to extract data:

`SELECT [field 1], [date field 1], [date field 2] from [Sheet1$]`

`SELECT [field 1], [date field 1], [date field 2] from [Sheet1$] where [field 1] = "sample values"`

I'm sure the "date field 2" contains valid date values (but emptied for the first 20 rows)
and the java program always return null for that column.

So, my question is will the empty value of [date field 2] of initial rows, says 8 rows, affect behavior of the JDBC/ODBC? If yes, how to avoid it (without sorting the data in the excel file)?

-- Edit --
Actually, I'm asking if the empty values of that field in the first few rows (say 8) will make the driver fail to extract the value of that column (even if the subsequent rows contain valid value). I'm also confused if it is implementation-specific that the driver will simply refuse to extract that field, returning null for all conditions, and even not to attempt to treat the column as string-type or return empty string (instead of NULL)

-- Edit --
Referring to the information in this KB: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/141284

The empty value of the first few rows in [date field 2] will make the ODBC driver return NULL under all conditions. So the root cause is found and what next is to find alternative JDBC driver for Excel files.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking if JDBC can handle null columns (of course it can!).  Or are you asking how your code should respond if it encounters a null?  Or are you asking something else entirely?  Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Excel ODBC driver will not properly identify the column as a date column if the first 8 rows are blank, so trying to get a date value for *all other* rows will not be successful. There is no way around this, it's not a Java-specific issue.

I'm not very familiar with JDBC, but if you're calling a method to return a date value for the field, try calling the method to pull the string value, then parse the string yourself into a date value (if that doesn't work, call the method that returns a floating-point value, since that's how Excel dates are stored internally).

Or, the *much* better solution is to NOT use Excel's ODBC driver (which is notoriously buggy and limited) and use the Apache POI library instead, which can read the Excel files natively. You lose the syntactic sugar of querying, but a simple loop through the active rows to find your data will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but I still need a SQL-enabled JDBC driver for Excel to fit the feature requirement.

Comment: If you can alter the spreadsheet then you can either sort the rows so that there are values for each of the date fields in at least one of the first eight rows or you could insert some dummy data with all fields populated into the first row of the spreadsheet (and skip that row in your query)